# What do you call this type of top down, not really 3D, perspective?

Tags: illustration, perspective

It's not isometric, it's not one point, maybe top down?

I want to Google it and don't know how.

Thanks
[image: car]

Comment: Artistic oblique?

Comment: Here's another one: http://i.imgur.com/PkChV9a.png

Comment: It's somewhat isometric, but not quite.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's closest to a view called a *three-quarters* view, a type of [axonometric projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometric_projection), in between a side view and top down one. It's "[a] method of portraying three dimensional space in a two-dimensional plane ... [very] popular during the 16-bit era for JRPGs." <sup>[source](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThreeQuartersView)</sup>.

[image: three-quarters view example]

It's still used in games today because of the high performance and artistic draw.

The style is also part of a more broad category of [2.5D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D), which comes in many forms. For more guidance on types of projection, check out [this article](https://medium.com/retronator-magazine/game-developers-guide-to-graphical-projections-with-video-game-examples-part-1-introduction-aa3d051c137d).

Comment: Agree with DA01 (+1). Now I am dying to use 2.5D in my next project. Lol.

Comment: Glad to be usefully making so many people learn new terms :)

Comment: This isn't really 2.5D.  That term more refers to 3D character models on a 2D plane.  One term you might try associating with this is "Isometric", which is what a lot of top-down psudo-3d games used.

Comment: It looks like the person who made this tilted the hood of the car down to try to simulate the tilt of a real car hood, and not to force any sort of perspective. I agree that the term for this type of perspective it is 2.5D

Answer (score 16):

It's not truly perspective. It's an artistic interpretation of a 3D element, but not adhering to any mathematical perspective grid.

The closest to a true type perspective would be [one point perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_%28graphical%29#One-point_perspective).

It could also be considered [foreshortening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_%28graphical%29#Foreshortening) outside of the perspective context.

Comment: I didn't know the term foreshortening until now :)

Comment: @ZachSaucier we're schooling each other today! :)

Comment: Glad to be usefully making so many people learn new terms :)

Comment: If I were a painter or historyan I would call that a cubist interpretation of the objects, where you have multiple points of view at the same time. The perspective of the wheels are planar, but you still can see an almost orthogonal top view.

Comment: @Rafael cubist is a good way to describe it!

Answer (score 12):

I don't think this illustration follows any of the strict formal Cartesian perspective models. If you try to find a vanishing point using edges that would have been parallel in the "real world" you will notice that there is none.

[image]

The front of the car seems to follow, loosely, a one point perspective model. The rest of the car, though, follows an isometric projection, since most edges are almost parallel when they are in the same plane.

I think the illustrator might have taken the liberty to mix and match the projection method to add energy and quirkiness to the illustration. Isometric projections make objects looks small, sort of like toys, which might have been his intention. Maybe (guessing) he modified it a bit to suggest movement, since if the car was moving, you would not would have been able to see all the parts of the car at once. Or maybe he just played with it until he liked it : )

Comment: Thanks, but it was just an example, you can consider all your red lines 90º. :)

Comment: Ah, then Zach's your guy.

Comment: Indeed he is. :)

Comment: If you ignore the bumper, it almost looks like some kind of inverted perspective (i.e. vanishing point is "in front of" the car).

Comment: @Random832: It occurs to me that an inverted perspective might be an interesting way to show more sides at once, but retain the general shape and angle.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for a common term, this might be called [bird's eye view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird%27s-eye_view).

Comment: Bird? In some years will be known as Drone's view n_n